# Get and set value spinner from other activity in android

Tags: android

I have code like this -mainclass-

```
 Spinner pilihtype;
 ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = 
 ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.typestore, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

 adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
 pilihtype=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.Stype);
 pilihtype.setAdapter(adapter);
```

it show my spinner value and it works

And now i Have a editclass that have spinner too. I want my spinner in editclass setvalue from selected value in mainclass , Can u give me a solution?? thanks

Comment: pass the value of the selected item to the editclass using spinner and do the task that displays the spinner according to the selected value

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the selected value as part of 'Extras' to your Intent. `intent.putExtra()` , `intent.getExtra()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Spinner pilihtype;
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter =  ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.typestore, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
pilihtype=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.Stype);
pilihtype.setAdapter(adapter);
```

From your current activity

```
Intent i = new Intent(YourActivity.this, nextActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("SpinnerValue",pilihtype.getSelectedItem().toString());
i.putExtras(bundle);
StartActivity(i);
```

In your next Activity

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String selectedItem = bundle.getString("SpinnerValue");
```

Comment: and how to change that string in value spinner ?